# Identify SMB with marking EGE

Tags: identification

See photo of PCB and SMB with marking EGE.

I cannot find any info on what the component is.  Any ideas or thoughts?

It appears to be on the 240V output from the relay which runs to a 15W halogen globe.   Both those EGE appear to be parallel from multimeter testing.

[image]

Comment: Looks like plain SMD resistors. You're reading them upside down. It's 3X3. Where the X is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet 393 so 39kohm smd resistor..

Comment: don't I feel like a goose!  upside down!  Let me pull the non cooked one off and test it.

Comment: My car has a cap marked '710' on the engine - what does it do??
it looks like they've been subjected to severe overvoltage - they look cratered. If it were a long term overload, they'd be burned. Also there appears to be some arc flash. Maybe there was a lightning strike that coupled a large spike into the circuit?

Comment: @kartman yeah it’s a 15 year old fridge control board.    I replaced the resistors today and same drama.   The board has a terrible layout so troubleshooting is garbage.   There is a million triacs, some under piezo and transformers.        I replaced the resistor, no other visible or easily identifiable damage, but bullet and bought a new control board.      The font really tricked me on this one.   Never seen such a square font on them before.   As soon as Damian said it I was just #facepalm.  Can’t believe it didn’t pick that up.

Comment: I dare say there was collateral damage. The resistor wasn’t ‘cooked’ as the pcb would show signs of overhearing. Instead there was a voltage high enough that it arced over the resistor. An arc is very low impedance, so at that point the resistor failed to exist. Whatever was on the other side took the brunt methinks.

Comment: Could be solder cracks over time with vibration, then you have tiny sparks starting to form as an inductive load, over the years gets bigger and eat out until failure.